# Can we publish a method Action to an exchange using RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, rabbitmq, queue

I want to know if its possible to publish a method Action using RabbitMq, C#. So instead of queuing an object, i want to queue a Function(or Action) whose params vary and publish it and the consumer(Async) should just be able to execute the Function(or Action). My goal is to have a generic message queue to be able to receive and accommodate any function call. Previously, i was sending objects and would serialize, encode them publish and at the consumer would deserialize and execute but now i have more than one functions to be queued which vary by params type so don't want to expose each of the params type when queuing the message instead need to address them in more generic way.
I'm also open to any other approach that can make it more generic. Please, guide.

Previously, I used to send

```
public void QueueObject(object obj, string type) // can i pass Action here instead of obj and type?
{
    IBasicProperties prop = model.CreateBasicProperties();
    prop.Persistent = true;
    prop.ContentType = "application/json";
    prop.Type = type;
    string jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); 
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonObj); 

    model.BasicPublish("", queueName, prop, buffer);//how can i publish a Action and receive it at consumer?
}

 public void DispatchQueueMessages()
    {
        model.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(model);
        model.BasicGet(queueName, autoAck: true);

        consumer.Received += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            string messageType = args.BasicProperties.Type;
            var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Body.Span);
            Object param = null;
            if(messageType.Equals(nameof("ABCType1")))
            {
                param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ABCType1>(jsonString); //I don't want to expose 
                                                      any ABCType1 here and want to make it generic
            }
            var response = await ExecuteMessageinQueue(param, messageType);
            ...//handle response here, yes i care about the response and want to handle them even when passed as an Action
            ...
         }
       }
```

From differentclass.cs,
I want to invoke like this

```
 msgQ.QueueObject(() => client.SendABCStatusAsync(id, abcStatus));//abcStatus is an object of ABCType1
 ..
 msgQ.QueueObject(() => client.GiveXYZStatusAsync(id, xyzStatus, info));//xyzStatus is an object of XYZType2
```

Comment: You can only publish things that are serializable. Actions are not serializable. If what you want is to invoke code on a client, then why not just define a web API and invoke that instead? RabbitMQ is absolutely the wrong tool here.

Comment: Thanks @JeffE: In such case, how do i use a queue to  ensure all my message are sent in order received and i also want to ensure it is re-queue in case server is down. If i have to just use web API, i may lose some msgs recieved in case of internal server error

Comment: Also, here our client is auto generated and also we post http request asynchronously inside of each of this method we invoke(ie ex, SendABCStatusAsync) by client. Since we don't want to mess up with generated client, we want to send SendABCStatusAsync and GiveXYZStatusAsync in queue.